# adding globally visible style template to silverlight custom control

Tags: silverlight, xaml, user-controls

I'm creating a custom control and I want to have style templates that can be used across the control (ie; other xaml files).  If this were an application, I'd have Application as my top-level Element and I could have Application.Resources that would be visible.  Here, my top-level element is UserControl.  Where can I put Style Template resources and how can I access them from other xaml docs?

EDIT:

You can also add a ResourceDictionary as a new item and import it into your other xaml files like so:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary  Source="Resources.xaml"/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put it in your top level element

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    ...
<UserControl.Resources>
```

If you want to share this among other UserControls in different file put it in a generic.xaml file in a folder called Themes